# Object oriented library on top of win32 that do not require control of main event loop

Tags: c++, windows, qt, winapi

I am implementing a plug-in in C++ on Windows for a 3rd party program.

I need my plug-in to display a GUI window as long as the 3rd party program is running.

I started programming in win32 directly. This works fine and I am able to to create a new window and register a callback function that receives all windows events inside my window even if I return control to the 3rd party program:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM) {
    ...
}

void createWindow() {
    WNDCLASS wndclass;
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    ...
    RegisterClass(&wndclass);
    HWND hwnd = CreateWindow(...);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, ...);
}
```

The problem with this approach is that win32 is low-level and not object oriented.
**Could you please recommend a GUI library that is lightweight and of high quality?**

**Earlier I have used Qt a lot and it is great, but as far as I understand it is not possible to use Qt without control of the main event loop?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WTL, Windows Template Library,  http://sourceforge.net/projects/wtl/ is a lightweight wrapper of the Windows API.  You still need to know the API to use it, but it is OO.  It uses a much more modern C++ approach than MFC.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be interested in [qtwinmigrate](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt-solutions/qt-solutions/source/1b2773642cc630d4772c2c1213e767e243d53517%3aqtwinmigrate) solution for Qt. This lets you mix the legacy win32 code, with Qt code. Qt is a very nice framework.